# I can't find my folder anywhere

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8

I had a folder full of random images of me and my family, more than 100, and yesterday I tried searching for it on my desktop (where it has always been) and couldn't find it.

I tried keyword searching for the folder name, some of the image names, in every drive and could not find anything. I suspected I might have accidentally deleted it, so I downloaded a recovery program called DMDE, but I could not find anything. And now, I have tried using a program called Recuva (as I found out from Google that it is the most recommended one).

I searched with it in my recycle bin, and did not find a single file of that folder. Then, I tried searching my whole C drive, and again, no image files of the ones I 'could have' deleted. And finally, I searched my Desktop (as that was the location of the folder) for images only, but couldn't find anything.

Note that, I did find a lot of old files I had deleted before with these programs, but not any of the ones I have been searching for. I found some old images that I have deleted, but not a single one from the implied folder.

I suspected I might have just moved it to another folder, but I checked and didn't find it, and also the keyword search didn't show anything. I'm currently scanning my whole computer for image files, but I doubt that I will find them.

What else can I do? How could they have disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make sure, that all files are visible via `folder options` and if you search for them, that they can be indexed (file properties). I think you already know that and I can't imagine this is the real reason you didn't find them.
- Files and folders with with invalid names / paths might still be visible via an alternative File Explorer like [TotalCommander](https://www.ghisler.com/) (e.g. file path too long, dollar sign or dot as first character)
- Your search index might have been [damaged](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-solve-windows-search-issues-index-rebuild/).
- Look into all folders `C:\Users\*differentnames*\Desktop`. You could have simply moved the files out of sight.
- The Desktop is a special folder in windows.
  If you deleted / manipulated your user account, chances are that you also lost your desktop items for this user.
- This is not the only special thing about the desktop. Usually the desktop is not really at the place it appears. It is connected to its real place by a junction. [Info about junctions](https://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/). [Creating junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html). [Finding junctions on your pc](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html).